# Does the Fourier series of a contiuous function help to study its dynamics?

Tags: complex-analysis, dynamical-systems, fourier-series, ergodic-theory

I am trying to connect things I learned and combine the ideas in Functional Analysis with other areas that I know so I can understand both of them better. So here's a question I got in my mind:

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is a continuous function in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. One knows that $f + i \cdot0$ belongs to the space $L^2(\mathbb{C})$. So we could naturally ask the question that what information could we get from the Fourier series of $f$ about the dynamics of the group $\langle f \rangle$ acting on $\mathbb{R}$? Do other possible estimates of $f$ with another family of functions help us in that regard? What properties of the dynamics of $\sin$ and $\cos$ waves/functions could be inherited by $f,$? Can we choose some specific $g$ for an initial $f$ so that $ f+ i.g  \in L^2(\mathbb{C}) $ and study the dynamics of $f$ by understanding the dynamics of the group $ \langle f,g \rangle$ using the Fourier series of $ f + i \cdot g $? Could we restrict ourselves with studying the dynamics of only the members of this family (trigonometric polynomials) or a finite linear combination of them? What about other families that estimate $f$? Could we generalize these ideas on other spaces like manifolds or Hilbert Spaces?

Comment: How are you defining the Fourier series of a function on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: You're right. My question has an issue. Maybe we can suppose $f$ is the real part of a complex valued function on $\mathbb{R}$ which belongs to $L^2(\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: My point was more that Fourier series are not defined on arbitrarily large intervals.. That is the purview of the Fourier transform.

Comment: I edited the question. Niw what I mean by the Fourier series of $f+ig$ is its representation as an infinite sum of the functions of the form $c_n.e^{inx}$ where $n$ is an integer.

Comment: just because $f$ and $g$ are bounded doesn't mean that $f+ig$ (or $f$, or $g$) are in $L^2$.

Comment: What if we take $g$ as zero?

Comment: it doesn't change anything. if you want $f$ to be in $L^2$, then you need some kind of condition on its growth at infinity. for instance, if $|f(x)| \leq \frac{C}{1+x^2}$ for some constant $C>0$

Comment: but in any case, I am almost sure the answer to the question that you want to ask is : there is no link between the dynamics of a function $f$ and its Fourier coefficients (if they exist).

Comment: You're right. I'm making a bad mistake. Then let me assume that $f$belongs to $L^2$ at the first place.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105400/discussion-between-glougloubarbaki-and-master-aka).

Comment: It seems that the discussion went outside dynamics. I'm only commenting on the dynamics: yes, it is quite common to use Fourier series more or less as you describe, with the difference that more often we have another dynamics and we find properties of the $L^2$ functions (and so also $L^1$ functions) that are invariant under the dynamics using Fourier series. And yes, we usually use only trigonometric polynomials.